# When is a symbolic link not acceptable?

Tags: symlink

From the **user** point of view, **for the purposes of *file content*, [symbolic link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) is the same as the target file**:

> Symbolic links operate transparently for most operations: programs that read or write to files named by a symbolic link will behave as if operating directly on the target file.

However, it appears that there are situations when a symbolic link cannot be used instead of the actual file ([Symbolic links to icns files are ignored on Mac OS X](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/159897/symbolic-links-to-icns-files-are-ignored)).

Are there any other examples in more conventional unixes?

Specifically, are there situations when a symbolic link cannot be used instead of the actual file?

The aspects I am aware of (and thus not interested in) are:

1. Of course, there are many examples of unix commands distinguishing symlinks from their targets (`ls`, `stat`, `find` &c). However, these commands deal with *files* as file-system objects, not their *contents*.
2. Other examples include security measures (e.g., `ftp` or `apache` refusing to `get` a link to a file outside the tree).
3. Still more examples can be invented using "power tools" (e.g., `emacs` can behave differently depending on whether called on a symbolic link).
4. A developer *can*, of course, easily distinguish between files and links - and thus screw the user over. So, when did they *actually* screw the user (for no good reason, like with the Mac icons above)?

Comment: Those situations where symlinks are actively rejected usually have to do with security concerns. E.g. `apache` will by default refuse to serve symlinks as web content, because you could construct a symlink to a file that only the `apache` process is allowed to read, and then request that symlink via HTTP, bypassing the security.

Comment: At a lower level (C API), there is always a way to distinguish a link from a file, either by a flag (`O_NOFOLLOW`) or by a different set of functions for each type (`stat` / `lstat`). For this reason, the decision of whether or not a link should be treated transparently belongs to the developer, and can therefore vary from one application to another, without any specific kind of "rule" to be applied.

Comment: Dropbox would be an example. It requires the folder to be named `Dropbox` and actually be a folder.

Comment: This is 100% application dependent, i.e., there's no rule. As J. Smith already pointed out.

Comment: @goldilocks: apps can do that, yes, but the question is about system-imposed restrictions.

Comment: Are you looking for examples where a program does it for no good reason, or are programs doing it for good reasons (not on your list) OK?

Comment: @derobert: I think all examples would be interesting; should I turn this into a community wiki to facilitate many answers?

Comment: @sds Taking "the system" to be the kernel, then no, there aren't any restrictions this way -- if you can make the symlink, the symlink is what it is.  Taking "the system" to refer to anything else involves application software, which again would be 100% arbitrary.  There are no general rules here at all.

Comment: One common error is that the programmer is unaware that system calls like `rename` operate on the symlink itself and not the target. Text editors take pains not to overwrite a file because it can become damaged if there isn't enough disk space, so they call `rename("file","file~")`, then write to `file`, then, if that succeeds, `unlink("file~")`, resulting in the symlink being replaced by an ordinary file and the target not being modified at all.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick: this is applicable to bad editors only. I doubt that either emacs or vim suffer from this.

Comment: @sds Yes, I should have qualified that with "It is unlikely that modern or actively maintained text editors do this".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not move any directory pertaining to a Solaris package to a different directory then use a symbolic link to fix the path.

While it will work initially, as soon as you install either a patch or a new package that share some part of the previous pakage path, the symbolic link will be removed and replaced by a plain directory by the Solaris package management commands.